# Field vs. Method in C++ class std::numeric_limits

Tags: c++, oop, numeric-limits

Why, in the template class `std::numeric_limits` in C++, is `digits` (and others) defined as a (static const) field of the class, but `min()` and `max()` are methods, since these methods just return a litteral value ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've always wondered that myself, especially since before the appearance of `constexpr` one could thus not use `min()` and `max()` in template parameters!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not allowed to initialize a non integral constant (eg: floating point) in a class body.
In C++11 the declaration changed to

```
...
static constexpr T min() noexcept;
static constexpr T max() noexcept;
...
```

To retain compatibility to C++98 the functions are kept, I think.

Example:

```
struct X {
    // Illegal in C++98 and C++11
    // error: ‘constexpr’ needed for in-class initialization
    //        of static data member ‘const double X::a’
    //        of non-integral type
    //static const double a = 0.1;

    // C++11
    static constexpr double b = 0.1;
};

int main () {
    std::cout << X::b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "It is not allowed to declare a non integral constant (eg: floating point)" ?

Comment: In C++03 only integral constants can be defined inside the class body. Nothing stops you from defining a floating point constants outside of the class body though.